# ms-access: proper syntax for a long condition statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

here's my condition:

```
([Panels] like '*something*' or [Panels] like '*something1*') AND ([Panels] like '*something2*' or [Panels] like '*something3*')
```

another words, here is the logic:

[Panels] has to be one of the following `(IT_AMPH |  AMPH_SN | AMPH_S)` AND it has to be one of the following: `(IT_BARB | BARB_SN | BARB_S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `In`

```
[Panels] In ('IT_AMPH','AMPH_SN ','AMPH_S')
AND [Panels] In ('IT_BARB','BARB_SN','BARB_S')
```

This will return `True` if `[Panels]` is in both lists.

If you want to use exclusively `and` and `or`... well, it can be a real headache:

```
([Panels]='IT_AMPH' AND [Panels]='AMPH_SN ' AND [Panels]='AMPH_S')
OR ([Panels]='IT_BARB' AND [Panels]='BARB_SN' AND [Panels]='BARB_S')
```

Hope this helps you.

---

If you need to use wildcards, you can replace the `=` with `Like`:

```
([Panels] Like '*IT_AMPH*' AND [Panels] Like '*AMPH_SN*' AND [Panels] Like '*AMPH_S*')
OR ([Panels] Like '*IT_BARB*' AND [Panels] Like '*BARB_SN*' AND [Panels] Like '*BARB_S*')
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You can replace '=' with 'Like', and you can use wildcards